# Why objects not being garbage collected while executing Java Stream terminal operation?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-stream

I'm trying to understand what holds the reference to the objects so that they are not eligible for garbage collection when Java Stream terminal operation is being executed ?

Here is my test code

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Scratch {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Stream<LargeObject> objectStream = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1000000).mapToObj(LargeObject::new);
       objectStream.peek(obj -> {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(1);

               if (obj.i % 100 == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Processed: " + obj.i);
               }

               if (obj.i % 10000 == 0) {
                   System.out.println("Calling GC");
                   System.gc();
               } 

           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       })
         .map(largeObject -> new Object())
         .count();
   }

   private static class LargeObject {
       private final int i;
       private final byte[] alloc = new byte[1024];

       private LargeObject(int i) {
           this.i = i;
       }

       @Override
       protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
           super.finalize();
           System.out.println("" + i + " collected");
       }
   }
 }
```

LargetObject's finalize method is never called.

My thought was that once .map(largeObject -> new Object()) is executed then nothing holds a strong reference to the LargeObject and it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Why this does not happen ? And maybe something could be done indeed ?

Comment: This may well be just that `finalize()` and `System.gc()` aren't actually going to let you observe this behavior.

Comment: I used the same 'peek' function code with List and it's List.iterator(), removing the objects while iterating.
finalize() method is called

Comment: Did you actually monitor the RAM usage with a profiler?

Comment: It's steady (~1.3G), does not go down.
I was using -Xmx1500m for this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with finalization and `gc`. You should have mentioned that you are on `java-9` or higher (I assume so, but it should be the case). I'll simplify this :

```
    long howMany = List.of(1, 2, 3)
                       .stream()
                       .map(x -> {
                           System.out.println("mapping = " + x);
                           return x;
                       })
                       .count();

    System.out.println(howMany);
```

Since the initial Stream has a known size, and that is not altered, your `peek` and `map` are not executed at all (as such no garbage generated). See this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3);
    Stream<Integer> one = isSized(list.stream());
    Stream<Integer> two = isSized(one.map(x -> {
        System.out.println("mapping = " + x);
        return x;
    }));

    long count = isSized(two).count();

    System.out.println(count);
}

private static Stream<Integer> isSized(Stream<Integer> stream) {
    Spliterator<Integer> sp = stream.spliterator();
    System.out.println(sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED));
    return StreamSupport.stream(sp, stream.isParallel());
}
```

Compile the same code with java-8 and you will see a different picture.

Comment: My bad, the version of the code I posted appeared a bit different than what I had played with. My version was with Collectors.toList(), and there were these lines as well: `List<LargeObject> objects = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 1000000).mapToObj(LargeObject::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
Stream<LargeObject> objectStream = objects.stream();
objects = null;`

The answer is correct for the code I posted.